# Mathematica 11 in Ubuntu 18.04 does not display special characters in the notebook

Tags: display, ubuntu

"Special" character, like pi (esc p esc), don't appear. They are instead replaced by a dotted gray square:
[image]

How can I change this? Mathematica worked just fine before I upgraded Ubuntu to 18.04. I thought this could be solved by uninstalling and installing it again. I finally came around to do it, and it didn't work.

Comment: Just an idea: check that mathematica font package is installed https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-contrib-i386/fonts-mathematica_20_all.deb.html, if not install it

Comment: To clarify, this isn't talking about "terminal" as in command-line interface, right? You mean the notebook interface? That's what's in your screenshot, at least.

Comment: @CarlLange Yeah, sorry. That's what I meant

Comment: @PicaudVincent This didn't work, I still have the problem

Comment: @pullux33, sorry it did not work, it was something to check. unfortunatelly I have no other suggestion right now